# How to override "Link To" settings in Gutenberg gallery block

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, wordpress-gutenberg, add-filter

Is there a way how to force an existing Gutenberg galleries to link to media files regardless what is set in the "Link To" option? Thanks.

Something like this filter hook which works for classic editor's galleries:

```
    add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_gallery',
        function( $out ){
            $out['link'] = 'file'; 
            return $out;
        }
    );
```

Comment: I dont think it is possible in Gutenberg gallery, as in GB, gallery block is rendered with JS only.

Comment: It is possible. There are also hooks for blocks